# I need to create an applescript to get the token from an account in the Authy desktop app and concatenate it with a password

Tags: macos, applescript

I was able to identify the names of some elements to make the click command, but I could not find the name of the element that identifies the accounts.

The idea is to click on an account, copy the token and concatenate it with a password inside the script

Commands already used:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Authy Desktop"
        set visible to true
        return every UI element of front window         
    end tell
end tell
```

---

```
tell application "System Events" to return value of every attribute of window of application process "Authy Desktop"
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately as Authy Desktop is an Electron app its accessibility features are not activated by default but there's a solution. (https://github.com/JonathanGawrych/set-electron-app-accessible):

```
tell application "System Events"
    set pid to unix id of first process whose name is "Authy Desktop"
    do shell script "/path/to/set-electron-app-accessible " & pid
end tell
```

in total my script currently looks like this (a few hardcoded values might need to be replaced):

```
tell application "System Events"
    set pid to unix id of first process whose name is "Authy Desktop"
    do shell script "/path/to/set-electron-app-accessible " & pid
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Authy Desktop"
        set visible to true
        delay 1
        click static text "<NAME OF THE ACCOUNT>" of group 2 of group 2 of group 1 of group 1 of UI element "Twilio Authy" of window "Twilio Authy" of application process "Authy Desktop" of application "System Events" -- Open account
        delay 1
        set codes to value of static text of (group 4 of group 1 of group 1 of UI element "Twilio Authy" of window "Twilio Authy" of application process "Authy Desktop" of application "System Events") -- Extract the UI elements showing the codes
        set code to last item of codes -- First 2 elements contain each one half (3 digits) of the code, last element contains the whole 6 digit code
        delay 1
        click group 1 of group 1 of group 1 of UI element "Twilio Authy" of window "Twilio Authy" of application process "Authy Desktop" of application "System Events" -- Go back to the overview
        delay 1
        set visible to false
    end tell
end tell
```

after that, `code` contains the 6 digit security code!